# How can I create click and drag for a 3D Jenga game in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, game-mechanics, physics-engine

Essentially, I am trying to create a game that mimics Jenga. Right now I have made it so that the blocks collide with each other and have gravity, everything works very well. The one thing that I am missing is the ability to click on a block and drag it out of the tower. I am using C# on Unity 3D. I am not the best at programming myself, so I used some other code and it ended up not working.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class mouseDrag : MonoBehaviour
{  
    public GameObject Cube;

    float distance = 10;

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance);
        Vector3 objPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        transform.position = objPosition;
    }
}
```

The name of the Jenga piece is called "Cube". I am not sure if I used the:

```
public GameObject Cube;
```

correctly in this instance. Also, right now I have a single Jenga piece but will need many more in the end. Does that have an effect on the code? Does the object name even need to be referenced at all? I am looking for a way that my mouse click could move any object with physics in the game.

[image]

When I run the game, everything seems fine, however as soon as I click and start to drag on the Jenga piece it gives me this error.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   mouseDrag.OnMouseDrag () (at Assets/mouseDrag.cs:12)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

This game will eventually be made for mobile devices.